# How to add a button using Higher Order Component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add a button to a component using higher order component? I tried this but its not adding the button inside the component. Its adding it before the original component.

```
const withButton = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
}
export default withButton
```

When I call the HOF like this

```
const ComponentWithButton = withButton(WrappedComponent)
```

ComponentWithButton has button added but its adding before WrappedComponent whereas I want to add button inside as a child of the WrappedComponent.

Lets say that WrappedComponent is rendering something like

```
<div className="baseClass">{other divs and layout}</div>
```

const ComponentWithButton = withButton(WrappedComponent)

ComponentWithButton should render the following

```
<div className="baseClass">
<button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
{other divs and layout}
</div>
```

Comment: Please, clarify what do you mean by 'inside'. As a child? What should happen with WrappedComponent's own children? Please add an example for WrappedComponent and how you expect the layout to be modified by withButton.

Comment: Hi estus, yes i want button to be added inside the wrapped component as a child. The wrapped component already has basic styling and I just want to add button which will also be a part of the wrapped component when necessary

Comment: Did you try putting the button inside wrapped component ?
<Fragment>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props}> 
          <button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
          </WrappedComponent>
        </Fragment>

Comment: This still depends on WrappedComponent. Does `<WrappedComponent {...this.props}><button>...</button></WrappedComponent>` do what you want? Please, provide an example in case it doesn't.

Comment: If I add button inside the <WrappedComponent />, <WrappedComponent /> will only have button side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [props.children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), also refer to [React.Children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

```js
function ComponentWithButton({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

And then render:

```js
<ComponentWithButton>
  <WrappedComponent />
</ComponentWithButton>
```

With classes:

```js
class ComponentWithButton extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ComponentWithButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically place the button somewhere inside the WrappedComponent, you can try something like this.

```
const withButton = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>
            <button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
          </WrappedCompnent>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
}
export default withButton
```

Now in your wrapped component, you can place the button any where you want as the button would be accessible as a property children to WrappedComponent.

```
const WrappedComponent = ({ children, ...otherProps }) => (
  <div className="baseClass">
    {children}
    {renderOtherDivsAndProps(otherProps)}
  </div>
);
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I am getting what I am looking for.

```js
const withButton = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>
            <button>BUTTON ADDED USING HOC</button>
            {this.props.children}
          </Wrappedcomponent>
      )
    }
  }
}
export default withButton
```